# send large file via HttpSendRequest

Tags: c++, file, send

How can I send a large file (more than 2gb) with `HttpSendRequest`?

Comment: I'm not on windows but these three links seems to provide initial guiding: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106816/how-to-contruct-httpsendrequest-method-of-wininet
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307919/upload-file-using-http-getting-error-httpsendreuest-12005
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130880/uploading-files-using-httpsendrequest-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to contruct HttpSendRequest method of WININET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106816/how-to-contruct-httpsendrequest-method-of-wininet)